# Can draw on form but not in a picture box in that form? c#

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap, draw, picturebox

I have made a WFA and I have a sub-form appear for the user.

In this form there is a picture box with a bitmap image inside and some labels and a button.

I made a little mini project to set up and try drawing on a form which worked fine, ive transferred that code over and rejigged it (i.e. change var names) and applied the mouse events and paint to the picture box instead of the form.

When i come to draw on the picture box it wont let me, however if i change what the .Paint(...) is applied to from the picture box to the form (this) i can draw on the form?

Am i missing something here/ doing something wrong?

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Valo.CustomDraw
{
    public delegate void PassValueHandler(Point [] pointAct);
    public partial class bitmap_Square : Form
    {
        public event PassValueHandler PassValue;
        public Point p1 = new Point(100, 100);
        public Point p2;
        Bitmap bmp;
        Point[] actualPoints;
        Graphics gr;

    public bitmap_Square(Bitmap b)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DoubleBuffered = true;

        this.bmp = b;
        pb_bitmapImage.Image = bmp;
        pb_bitmapImage.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;


        pb_bitmapImage.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.Form1_Paint);
        pb_bitmapImage.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Form1_MouseDown);
        pb_bitmapImage.MouseMove += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Form1_MouseMove);
        pb_bitmapImage.MouseUp += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Form1_MouseUp);
    }

    private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
            p1 = e.Location;
    }

    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            p2 = e.Location;
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            p2 = e.Location;
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;

        if (p1.X > 0 && p1.Y > 0 && p2.X > 0 && p2.Y > 0)
            g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, new Rectangle(p1.X, p1.Y, p2.X - p1.X, p2.Y - p1.Y));
    }

    private void btn_rectApply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (PassValue != null)
        {
            actualPoints[0] = p1;
            actualPoints[1] = p2;

            PassValue(actualPoints);
        }
        this.Close();

    }


    }
}
```

Thanks (Ignore the formatting of end braces, that's just how it copied over)

Jordan

Comment: this.Invalidate(); is invalidating your form not picture box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with your code except you call `this.Invalidate();` instead of `pb_bitmapImage.Invalidate()`. Otherwise that works fine.

`this.Invalidate(true);` also should work, but that will trigger unnecessary repaint to all children. So just use `pb_bitmapImage.Invalidate()`.

Actually Rectangle will be drawn when picturebox repaints, you need patience to see that :)

Comment: Aaaaah brilliant! its working now!

Thank you both, @Sriram_Sakthivel 

rookie mistake :)